# UIView KVO: Why don't changes to "center" cause KVO notifications for "frame"?

Tags: ios, uiview, key-value-observing

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of these mechanisms. I have a UIView that is touch enabled, and can update its own `center` property.

My understanding is that the `frame` property is a synthesized function of the `center` and `bounds`. Assuming that this is true, I put an observer on my touchable/movable view which observed its `frame` property. But that observer is never notified about the changes to frame (which happen automatically when `center` is changed). If I observe `center` directly, it works as expected.

Why doesn't observing `frame` work here?

---

Note that I know that I could be just observing `center` directly, which is fine. I can also surround the change to center with will/did methods for `frame`, which then also works:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"frame"];
[self setCenter:center];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"frame"];
```

But I mainly just want to understand why it doesn't work out of the box the way I expect it to work, in case I'm missing something conceptually here, either about KVO or about the view geometry.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I've had luck with doing KVO on the frame. Look here for how I did it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-get-a-callback-by-kvo-on-a-uiviews-frame-property

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason observing `frame` isn't working is because no UIKit property is defined to be KVO-compliant unless explicitly documented to be KVO-compliant.

You're not missing anything - Unfortunately UIKit doesn't support what you're trying to do with the observation.

Comment: Ah, well, fair enough then. The fact that `center` was notifying at all I guess is just undocumented luck. Thanks.

Comment: As Deepak notes below, you may have better luck observing `position`, but even then it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you can't observe for frame here because they are more-or-less derived values from the underlying model, the layer. All changes to `frame`, `center`, and `bounds` affect the layer properties. If you are keen on observing all changes to the above mentioned properties, you should observe the layer's `position` property.