# UIView frame change Notification

Tags: ios, uiview, notifications, frame

Is there any notification when frame or bounds of `UIView` changes? Whenever frame of a `UIView` changes, I need to calculate and set the frame of its custom subview so that it aspect fits in the superview.

`NSView` has the notification `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotfication` for the purpose. Why is this not there for `UIView`?

Comment: I've posted a solution on of how to do KVO on a UIViews frame. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-get-a-callback-by-kvo-on-a-uiviews-frame-property

Comment: See my answer here how to achieve this using method swizzling and a UIView category: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39345728/480467

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no notification. You can subclass UIView to override `layoutSubviews`, to either do the layout directly or send the necessary notification.

Have you tried setting an appropriate `autoresizingMask` so the subview gets resized automatically?