# iOS: How do I know if a property is KVO-compliant?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, key-value-observing

In the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), the section [Registering for Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) says "Typically properties in Apple-supplied frameworks are only KVO-compliant if they are documented as such." But, I haven't found any properties in the documentation that are documented as KVO-compliant. Would you please point me to some?

Specifically, I would like to know if the `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *rootViewController` of `UIWindow` is KVO-compliant. The reason is that I'm adding the `rootViewController` property to `UIWindow` for iOS < 4 and want to know if I should make it KVO-compliant.

```
@interface UIWindow (Additions)

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController;
#endif;

@end

@implementation UIWindow (Additions)

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
@dynamic rootViewController;

- (void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)newRootViewController {
    if (newRootViewController != _rootViewController) {
        // Remove old views before adding the new one.
        for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [_rootViewController release];
        _rootViewController = newRootViewController;
        [_rootViewController retain];
        [self addSubview:_rootViewController.view];
    }
}
#endif

@end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:  Nothing in UIKit is guaranteed to be KVO-compliant.  If you happen to find that KVO-ing a property works, be grateful, it's unintentional.  Also: be wary.  It could very well break in the future.

If you find that this is something you need, please [file an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).

---

About your actual code, it's inherently flawed.  Do *NOT* attempt to add a "rootViewController" setter to `UIWindow` this way.  It **will** break when you compile your code on iOS 4 but someone runs it on an iOS 5 device.  Because you compiled using the 4.x SDK,  the `#if` statements will evaluate to true, meaning your category method smasher will be included in the binary.  However, when you run it on an iOS 5 device, you're now going to get a method conflict because two methods on `UIWindow` will have the same method signature, and *there's no guarantee as to which one will be used*.

Don't screw with the frameworks like this.  If you have to have this, use a subclass.  THIS IS WHY SUBCLASSING EXISTS.

---

Your subclass would look something like this:

```
@interface CustomWindow : UIWindow

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end

@implementation CustomWindow : UIWindow

static BOOL UIWindowHasRootViewController = NO;

@dynamic rootViewController;

- (void)_findRootViewControllerMethod {
  static dispatch_once_t predicate;
  dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
    IMP uiwindowMethod = [UIWindow instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)];
    IMP customWindowMethod = [CustomWindow instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)];
    UIWindowHasRootViewController = (uiwindowMethod != NULL && uiwindowMethod != customWindowMethod);
  });
}

- (UIViewController *)rootViewController {
  [self _findRootViewControllerMethod];
  if (UIWindowHasRootViewController) {
    // this will be a compile error unless you forward declare the property
    // i'll leave as an exercise to the reader ;)
    return [super rootViewController];
  }
  // return the one here on your subclass
}

- (void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
  [self _findRootViewControllerMethod];
  if (UIWindowHasRootViewController) {
    // this will be a compile error unless you forward declare the property
    // i'll leave as an exercise to the reader ;)
    [super setRootViewController:rootViewController];
  } else {
    // set the one here on your subclass
  }
}
```

<sub>*Caveat Implementor*: I typed this in a browser window</sub>

Comment: Cool, thanks! So then, as a follow-up question, does the code look correct & good? This is the first time I'm adding an ivar via a category.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, I couldn't compile it for iPhone 4.3.1 device. I got `Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIWindow._rootViewController", referenced from:
      -[UIWindow(Additions) setRootViewController:] in UIWindow+Additions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`. So, I'll subclass it for iOS 3.2 I guess. A little more code, but that should do it! Thanks!

Comment: @MattDiPasquale just added an example of what your subclass might look like.

Comment: thanks! I went with a subclass as you suggested. But, what about using [Associative References with a category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)?

Comment: thanks for this. This is sweet! :) How do I forward declare a property? I know I could just do: `[super performSelector:@selector(rootViewController)]` and `[super performSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:) withObject: rootViewController]`

Comment: @DaveDeLong let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1246/discussion-between-mattdipasquale-and-dave-delong)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@David DeLong's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612523/ios-how-do-i-know-if-a-property-is-kvo-compliant/6612561#6612561), this is what I came up with, and it works beautifully.

Basically, I made a category on `UIWindow`. And in `+load`, I (run-time) check whether `[UIWindow instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(rootViewController)]`. If not, I use `class_addMethod()` to dynamically add the getter & setter methods for `rootViewController`. Also, I use `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` to get & set the `rootViewController` as an instance variable of `UIWindow`.

```
// UIWindow+Additions.h

@interface UIWindow (Additions)

@end

// UIWindow+Additions.m

#import "UIWindow+Additions.h"
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIWindow (Additions)

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
// Add rootViewController getter & setter.
static UIViewController *rootViewControllerKey;

UIViewController *rootViewController3(id self, SEL _cmd);
void setRootViewController3(id self, SEL _cmd, UIViewController *newRootViewController);

UIViewController *rootViewController3(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    return (UIViewController *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &rootViewControllerKey);
}

void setRootViewController3(id self, SEL _cmd, UIViewController *newRootViewController) {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [self performSelector:@selector(rootViewController)];
    if (newRootViewController != rootViewController) {
        // Remove old views before adding the new one.
        for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &rootViewControllerKey, newRootViewController,
                                 OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
        [self addSubview:newRootViewController.view];
    }
}

+ (void)load {
    if (![UIWindow instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(rootViewController)]) {
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(rootViewController),
                        (IMP)rootViewController3, "@@:");
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(setRootViewController:),
                        (IMP)setRootViewController3, "v@:@");
    }
}
#endif

@end
```

Comment: This is still a bad idea. Categories on Apple Framework objects should always prefix their method names to avoid clashes with future or private methods.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using [Associative References to define an instance variable with a category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html). But, it doesn't work cause, according to @Dave DeLong, I must use a [run-time (not compile-time) check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617832/run-time-vs-compile-time-iphone-version-check) for this.

```
// UIWindow+Additions.h

@interface UIWindow (Addtions)

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIViewController *rootViewController;
#endif

@end

// UIWindow+Additions.m

#import "UIWindow+Additions.h"
#include <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIWindow (Additions)

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
@dynamic rootViewController;

static UIViewController *rootViewControllerKey;

- (UIViewController *)rootViewController {
    return (UIViewController *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &rootViewControllerKey);
}

- (void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)newRootViewController {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = self.rootViewController;
    if (newRootViewController != rootViewController) {
        // Remove old views before adding the new one.
        for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [rootViewController release];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &rootViewControllerKey, newRootViewController,
                                 OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
        [rootViewController retain];
        [self addSubview:rootViewController.view];
    }
}
#endif

@end
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on @David DeLong's feedback, I went with a simple subclass like so:

```
// UIWindow3.h

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
@interface UIWindow3 : UIWindow {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end
#endif

// UIWindow3.m

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_4_0
#import "UIWindow3.h"

@implementation UIWindow3

@synthesize rootViewController;

- (void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)newRootViewController {
    if (newRootViewController != rootViewController) {
        // Remove old views before adding the new one.
        for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
        [rootViewController release];
        rootViewController = newRootViewController;
        [rootViewController retain];
        [self addSubview:rootViewController.view];
    }
}

@end
#endif
```

However, this also required going through the existing code and using conditional compilation to cast `UIWindow` to `UIWindow3` where ever `rootViewController` was being accessed. (Note: I think @David DeLong's solution may not require making these additional changes but rather just always using `CustomWindow` instead of `UIWindow`.) Thus, this is more annoying than if I could (only for iOS < 4) just add the `rootViewController` to `UIWindow` via a category. I may look into doing this with a [category using Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) (only for iOS < 4) because I think that looks like it'd be the most eloquent solution and might be a good technique to learn and have in the toolbox.

Comment: You still have the iOS 5 problems I mentioned previously.  You can't solve that problem with a compile-time check; it has to be a run-time check.