# How to know if a class is KVO compliant for a certain property?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I want to use KVO on a property say for UIView, but i don't know if it is compliant.
take for example "hidden" property.

I went to the header file of the UIView class, and couldn't find an indication, and i also went to the documentation of this property. Someone talked about 'checking the references for compliancy' what references is he talking about?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like they're referring (rather vaguely) to the KVC Compliance documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172

Specifically, you need to see if the class responds to `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` for a given key. The documentation is rather spare on how you should actually check for compliance. My first thought is wrap your code in a try/catch block, and catch the exception, but that probably won't work given how that exception is generally thrown.

The general assumption is most objects in UIKit are *NOT* KVO compliant, and if you need them to be, you can subclass and implement it. You can see a very similar question / duplicate here, with an answer from Dave Delong, the Apple Frameworks Evangelist:[iOS: How do I know if a property is KVO-compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612523/ios-how-do-i-know-if-a-property-is-kvo-compliant)

Comment: yep, i already read that question, but I'm searching for a way to tell if the property is KVC without trying it by code, and seeing if it works. I suspect there's a way to detect it faster.

Comment: Just to clarify, KVC (Key Value Coding) and KVO (Key Value Observing) are very different things. KVC is the ability to set/get properties using the methods you are describing. KVO is the ability to observe changes to properties using the `addObserver` methods. These are all easily confused with Key Value Compliance, which refers to a property being properly set up for Key Value Observing.