# UIButton set titleLabel setValue(newLabel, forKeyPath: "titleLabel")

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
let newLabel = UILbael()
let button = UIButton()
button.setValue(newLabel, forKeyPath: "titleLabel")
```

crash info

> `setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key valuecoding-compliant for the key titleLabel`

how do it if use kvc ?

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You post some code that doesn't really make sense and then say "how to do it." How do do **what**? Describe what you're trying do in words. Are you trying to copy the text from a label "titleLablel" into another label, "newLabel"? Are you trying to copy all the attributes of the label? (Size, position, font, etc.)

Comment: var button = button() set button.titlelabel use kvc

Comment: **don't** use KVC

Comment: Your question is still a gabled mess. What are the variables containing the 2 buttons? How is the first button created? Is `newLabel` a label, or are you hoping to copy the button title of one button to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setTitle` method to set button title for states.

```
button.setTitle("Your button title here", for: .normal)
```

[setValue(_:forKeyPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418139-setvalue) is a method from `NSObject` class which `UIButton` is a subclass of. It is not recommended to use KVO. Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612523/ios-how-do-i-know-if-a-property-is-kvo-compliant/6612561#6612561) for more information.

Comment: FYI: UIButton is not a subclass of NSObject, its inherited from UIControl

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh UIButton -> UIControl -> UIView -> UIResponder ->NSObject.

Comment: Accoding to this every class is subclass of NSObject :-p

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh Yes most UIKit objects are. Is there a word for saying subclass of subclass of subclass of subclass? I do not know if there is. :x

Comment: var button = button()   set button.titlelabel  use kvc

Answer (score 1):

KVC is only supported for NSObjects, and Apple seems to be phasing it out in Swift. I don't recommend using KVC for new development.

You also shouldn't use the button's `titleLabel` to set the button's title. To quote the Apple docs on UIButton:

> To set the actual text of the label, use `setTitle(_:for:)`
>   (button.titleLabel.text does not let you set the text).

If you have two buttons, `firstButton` and `secondButton`, and you're trying to copy the title from the first to the second, your code might look like this:

```
let title = firstButton.title(forState: .normal)
secondButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u have not confirmed your outlet in your ViewController that's a reason when use button and set title there are not any references of a button in ViewController. it's like the use of any object without any initialize. So make sure and check button outlet. Please see code so we make sure what is actual problem.

Comment: var button = button()   set button.titlelabel  use kvc