# Why UIButton can not use KVC to change titleLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, key-value-coding

```
let newLabel = UILbael()
let button = UIButton()
button.setValue(newLabel, forKeyPath: "titleLabel")
```

crash info

> `setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key valuecoding-compliant for the key titleLabel`

how do it if use kvc ?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: This is the same as your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907176/uibutton-set-titlelabel-setvaluenewlabel-forkeypath-titlelabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that you can't set the title label directly:

```
mybutton.titleLabel = UILabel(...)
```

The reason: it's a read-only property. You have no business trying to substitute a different label inside the button!

Comment: Yes, it can, if the property supports KVC. But you are trying to write to a read only property. KVC doesn’t let you magically do that.