# KVO on SKView is not being called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, key-value-observing, skview

I am trying to do KVO on an property of SKView but its not working.

I have tried it with .frame and it works like a charm, so why not also on .window ?

To clarify, I am using SpriteView in a SwiftUI app and I am trying to get the bounds of the View.
What I am after is to get the following before the App starts;

print (self.convertPoint(fromView: .zero) ). When I use this in

```
override func didMove
```

I'll get Nan/NaN. However Apple Code Level Support said this about using SpriteView and getting the bounds of a view.

> The reason you are receiving NaN is that you are calling these methods
> before the underlying SKView has been actually presented by SwiftUI,
> which is an event that you have no visibility into, and no way to call
> code when it happens.
>
> However, when this event does occur, the SKScene’s view property will
> have it’s window set from nil to a UIWindow.  Therefore, you could use
> KVO to observe when the window property is changed, and then make your
> calls to convertPoint once there is a non-nil window.

I have so far this:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    observe.observe(object: view )
}

class Observer:SKScene {
    var kvoToken: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    func observe(object: SKView) {
    kvoToken = object.observe(\.window , options: [ .new] ) { (object, change) in

        guard let value = change.newValue else { return }
        print("New value is: \(value)")
        print ("NEW", self.convertPoint(fromView: .zero) )
        
      }
    }
    
  deinit {
    kvoToken?.invalidate()
  }
}
```

I have also tried to add an observer like so :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(view.window, selector: #selector(test(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TestNotification"), object: nil)
```

The above doesn't seem to do anything. So I am kinda stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit more, perhaps the context will help?

Comment: Oh I see, so SwiftUI moves the scene to the view first, before presenting the view. Fair enough. How does the code not work? Does it not do anything?

Comment: its not being called, it works on \.frame but not on \.windows and I can't figure out why. Perhaps I am doing something wrong .. seriously I have no clue.

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612523/ios-how-do-i-know-if-a-property-is-kvo-compliant), it seems like that there is a high chance that `window` is not KVO compliant, and you can't observe it at all. Who is it that told you that you can observe it?

Comment: Code level support from Apple, and yes I saw that one as well. Thats why I come here for help :)

Comment: Huh, that is very weird. You see, I tried running `convertPoint` in `onAppear`, at which point the `SKView` should have been added to the window (confirmed with debugger that `self.view?.window != nil`), but `convertPoint` still gives me NaN. This seems to contradict their claim that the reason why `convertPoint` returns NaN is because of `window == nil`.

Comment: Yes , but if you print out convertPoint in for example, touchesBegan, it will give you the information that I so desperately need :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer (probably) ..

I couldn't read the '.window' property of UIView, so I started to look for another observable property that would change as soon as UIWindow is != nil. I think I have found it in SKScene.view.frame . I am not entirely sure that this is a 100% good answer but it works.

```
class Observer: NSObject {
    dynamic var kvoToken: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    func observe(object: SKScene )  {
        kvoToken = object.observe(\.view?.frame , options: [ .new] ) { (object, change) in

        guard let value = change.newValue else { return }
        print("New value is: \(value)")
        print ("CONVERTING", object.convertPoint(fromView: .zero) )
        
      }
    }
    
  deinit {
    kvoToken?.invalidate()
  }
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
    viewer = view.scene

    observe.observe(object: viewer )

}
```