# key value observers were still registered with it when controller is deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, key-value-observing, dealloc

I added an observer in the code and then removed it in dealloc and viewWillDisappear but still i am getting an error stating

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x167e5980 of
>   class MyController2 was deallocated while key value observers were
>   still registered with it.
>
> ```
> Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x16719f90> (
> <NSKeyValueObservance 0x16719fb0: Observer: 0x167e5980, Key path: dataContainer.report, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1677df30>
> )'
> ```

I created a controller, `MyController` and derive a new controller `MyController2` from it. Now i added KVO in `MyController2`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
```

Then in observeValueForKeyPath :-

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    id oldC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    id newC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataContainer.report"]) {
        if (oldC != newC) {
            //Remove Observer

            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" context:nil];
            [self updateDataContainer];
            [self reportView];
        }
    }
}
```

Then i tried to remove observer in viewWillDisappear and dealloc both :-

```
- (void)dealloc {
    @try{
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" context:nil];
    }@catch(id anException){
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    @try{
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" context:nil];
    }@catch(id anException){
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

I looked at lost of posts , all of them say one thing you need to remove observer. I tried to remove observer from both of them but still i am getting the issue.

Comment: The error shows that you are added observer for `dataContainer.inspectionReport` key path, but your code shows the key path as `dataContainer.report`.

Comment: @MidhunMP sorry actually i changed that part from code and forgets to change from error. Now i changed it. Please let me know if you find anything why i am getting the error

Comment: I'd suggest logging everywhere you add and remove observers and I bet you'll find they're not balanced.

Comment: @Rob I will try to do that. Also i thing i am not understanding why did i got i down vote. Atleast people who downVotes should also write the reason for it. So that i don't do that mistakes again

Comment: Are you adding observer from any other place ?

Comment: Get rid of the try/catch. In Objective-C, exceptions are for programming order. You _never_ catch them.

Comment: @gnasher729 I used this so that when i remove observer if it is not present , it would go to catch and app remains safe

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta - We understand why you added the exception handling (because you apparently don't reliably know whether the observer has been removed already or not), but you should never use exception handling for standard logic flow. Your app should know whether there is an observer to remove or not. Either simply the logic (e.g. some stateless single flow of logic add in `viewDidLoad` and remove in `dealloc`, so you don't have to worry about the state of the observer), or add some state variable to know whether you've removed it or not. But don't use exception handling in your code.

Comment: Re down-vote, I don't who down-voted, but I would guess it's because you haven't given us a reproducible example of the problem (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and it's not clear what diagnostic work you've done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**From my experience best way to add and remove observer in iOS.**

Add observer in ViewDidLoad:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
```

To observe the observer we have to do this:-

> Don't remove observer in observeValueForKeyPath

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    id oldC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
    id newC = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"dataContainer.report"]) {
        if (oldC != newC) {
            [self updateDataContainer];
            [self reportView];
        }
    }
}
```

Remove Observer In dealloc :

> call remove once here

```
- (void)dealloc {
    @try{
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" context:nil];
    }@catch(id anException){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have a boolean flag which you should set as true when observer is added and set it false on removing. Add observer only when this flag is false. 
Also add check in viewWillDisappear before removing observer. Also add log

```
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController || self.isBeingDismissed) {
        if (isReportKVOAdded) {
            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dataContainer.report" context:nil];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to remove observer as many time as you have added, this can be prevented by using flags

Comment: yeah Having a Bool for add and remove Observer is good idea . it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 KVO using KeyPath observers work on iOS 11 (and probably macOS 10.13)

```
    @objcMembers class Foo: NSObject {
        dynamic var string = "bar"
    }

    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation!

    func TestKVO() {

        var foo = Foo()

        // kvo in 2 lines of code
        observation = foo.observe(\.string) { observed, change in
            print(observed.string)
        }

        foo.string = "yo" // prints "yo"
        foo = Foo() // works on iOS 11, crashes MacOS 10.12, not tested on MacOS 10.13, yet
        foo.string = "oy" // does not print
    }
```

[macOS 10.13 and iOS 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html)

Comment: To note, I am using this technique but have had a few issues with it macOS 10.13.2 / XCode 9.2. I was getting some 'trying to access unowned self but it has already been deallocated' crashes on my observation closure. Adding deinit { observation?.invalidate() } to my class stopped the crashes - so something wasn't being cleaned up as it should.