# AVPlayerControllerTimeResolver instance is getting deallocated when I come from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Hi all I am facing a strange issue when I am playing a video my `AVPlayerControllerTimeResolver` instance is getting deallocated when I come from background to foreground.

My error log is given below -

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x170251610
>   of class AVPlayerControllerTimeResolver was deallocated while key
>   value observers were still registered with it. Current observation
>   info:  ( 
>   Context: 0x1b31fa9a0, Property: 0x17424e2b0> 
>   Context: 0x1b31fa9a8, Property: 0x17024ea90>  Context: 0x1b31fa9b0, Property: 0x1702507a0>
>    Context: 0x1b31fa9b8, Property: 0x170250050> )'

HERE IS MY CODE-

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    self.avpplayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avpplayerController?.player = player
    self.present(avpplayerController!, animated: true) {
        self.avpplayerController?.player!.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640432/key-value-observers-were-still-registered-with-it-when-controller-is-deallocated. It's in Objective c But you can convert it

Comment: @JeckyModi - Thanks for your response I am also facing this issue right now I am not setting any observer so why I am getting this observer issue. But as per your suggestion I am using this code    
    deinit {
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    } it is unable to solve my problem.

Comment: @PankajGupta will you share your demo ? I want to check it and want to solve it

Comment: @JeckyModi - Sorry due to some office security policy reason I can't share my code .

Comment: @PankajGupta It's ok