# How do I trigger an event when a UIImageView reaches a certain location?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, events, uiimageview, location

I have a `UIImageView` that moves around the screen, and I am trying to trigger a method when it is within a certain distance of another `UIImageView`, also moving. There is not necessarily any specific time I want to check, I want to know anytime it is within that distance. Help!

**EDIT:** I have multiple objects(the enemies) moving down the screen while the player is at the bottom of the screen. When the user taps the screen, it "shoots"(a new projectile object is created and the animation to move it up the screen is started). I am trying to detect when the "projectiles" hit the "enemies" and triggering an event(i.e. killing the enemy). I have no idea where to put the code to do this, or even what to do. Do I want to use the Notification System, or do I want to calculate if the projectile will hit the enemy as soon as it is fired?

Comment: what exactly is the problem: - is your problem the detection of the "collision" or where to implement the calculations? if your problem is where to implement, then please explain how you do the animation (the movement of the UIImageView objects).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-get-a-callback-by-kvo-on-a-uiviews-frame-property)'s an example.