# Keep distance between 2 objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a preferred way similar to `AutoSizing` to keep a 50 px of margin between 2 objects (`UIImageViews` for example) **without** using `AutoLayout` ?

I'm sure it's pretty simple writing something like that programmatically but I was wondering if there's something similar to that in the IB that I overlooked.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with AutoLayout? You can create `NSLayoutConstraint`s in code at runtime.

Comment: Nothing wrong but my apps are usually iOS 5 compatible.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to either make very clever use of autoresizing masks, or manually adjust the view frames every the size changes.

Comment: Use KVO on the frame? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-get-a-callback-by-kvo-on-a-uiviews-frame-property