# Make an image copy another images movements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I was surprised to find that I couldn't find another question like this. What I've done is made a uiimage moveable (by dragging it) and I would like another image to copy it's movements. Not go to the same position, but copy the movement. I had a go at this myself but I can't seem to get it right. I would appreciate some help. And go easy on me because I'm a very new developer :)
Thanks.

edit: I'll try to explain it a little better... If image 1 is dragged to the left, I want image 2 to look as if its part of image 1. They move in unison.

Comment: copy movements means? You want to make new Image?

Comment: Record the **amount of change** in x,y coords of image being dragged then apply the same amount of change to the other image.

Comment: Amar, that's what I was thinking to do but don't know how to do it. Would you be able to demonstrate?

Comment: Durgaprasad, I simply want an image to do what another image does. If the first image moves down the second image does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the frame of the Imageview within which you have the image. For that you can use KVO. Its already explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874289/1029360

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't understand how this can be used to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user2329585 Using the method I have mentioned above, you can get the frame of the first image imageview. You can use the frame obtained to position your second image imageview. I hope that's what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm looking for. I wasn't thinking straight, thanks for your help. :)