# Solid solution to flexibly resize UIView based on subviews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

Imagine you have four or so views, all width 100, different heights. You have a wrapper view W which holds them all.

```
A   |
B   |  W
C   |
D   |
```

the heights of the small views can change. At that time you want them all to move, float, appropriately, and resize W.

Now, I was just about to write a few lines of code to do this.

So .. (1) you'd have W find all the subviews and list them in order from top to bottom.  Then (2) each time there is a change, you'd (3) reposition each of ABCD.  the position of each one is the sum of the heights of the items above it, and (4) resize W to the sum of all heights.

Now that's all fine but -- idiots reinvent the wheel!

Am I missing something obvious in iOS?  is there already a package everyone uses to do this all the time? Or something built in? What's the situation?

(Note that of course frustratingly, for our Android friends this is built in! And of course any web-html system does this automatically.)

What's the right engineering solution for iOS views here?  For the record this is iOS7+ only, no old-fashioned stuffs need be covered, if it makes a difference.  Cheers

Comment: Have you come across the concept of Auto Layouts in iOS?

Comment: dude I HAVE NOT done a project with autolayouts .. do they completely solve the issue?  So, in the example, if I make C taller .. will it move D automatically, and make W bigger automatically?  Thank you

Comment: As long as you set D's constraints are set to be always present below C, yes. To make W bigger "automatically",  you always have `sizeToFit` if nothing works. :)

Comment: Use AutoLayout, your life will be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) you'd have W find all the subviews and list them in order from top
>   to bottom. Then (2) each time there is a change, you'd (3) reposition
>   each of ABCD. the position of each one is the sum of the heights of
>   the items above it, and (4) resize W to the sum of all heights.

You can use constraints in Interface Builder for that whole process, no code required. Do this:

- set the width of subview A to 100
- constrain B, C, and D to match A's width
- add vertical spacing constraints between A and B, B and C, and C and D to maintain their relative position
- add a vertical spacing constraint between W (the superview, shown in gray) and A
- add a vertical spacing constraint between W and D
- add leading and trailing space constraints between W and view A

You'll end up with something that looks like this:

[image: constraints]

The constraints editor in Xcode isn't completely intuitive, but it *is* easy to use once you understand what you can and can't do with constraints in IB and when you need to use code to set up the constraints.

Comment: Hi Caleb!  To be clear then.  **While the app is running**, if I change the height of say two of the items .... then, at that instant the other three will be moved so the relation remains?  Thanks.  Also, TBC, can you also do the "holding view" (W in my example) in some way purely in IB using your awesome technique?!  thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the point of auto layout. You create a set of constraints between views, and auto layout attempts to satisfy those constraints whenever any of the affected objects changes. I'll edit the answer to make it clear that the grey rectangle is your "holding view", W.

Comment: Astounding.  You could make things like, say, imagine a game where with your finger you can resize them. This "auto layout" thing you speak of, would, completely take care of moving the rest around. Thanks!  Why doesn't everyone use this all the time?!  I just did a thing with a collapsing panel.  I manually move the other stuff when it collapses: stupid, right?  I could just use this!

Comment: You're right -- it is very useful. It's also not all that new, having been introduced in iOS 6. Apple has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) that covers it all in detail -- you should read it.