# Hook on UIView's frame change from third party library

Tags: objective-c, uiview, frame

I am building a 3rd party library that I plan to integrate on different projects, so I need this to be as modular and have a non-destructive nature as possible. I need to "hook on" frame changes of `UIView`s. I am building a category and from that category method, I need to hook on that view's (it can be any regular `UIView` or subclass) frame change, and perform my additional logic. I've looked at KVO but as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701380/811405 it's not a safe approach.

How can I hook on frame change of a `UIView`? I can override `setFrame:` in my category, but I know that it is the single worst thing an Objective-C programmer can make: overriding a default method in a category. How do I achieve this?

**UPDATE:** I'm currently working on a really ugly (but working) solution:

- I've created an invisible (empty `drawRect:`) `UIView` subclass.
- I'm instantiating and adding it to the view of which I want to be notified of frame changes.
- I'm setting that view's (the "superview") autoresizesSubviews to `YES`.
- I'm setting my "invisible" view's autoresizing mask to both flexible width and height.
- I'm overriding my "invisible" view's `setFrame:` to notify the appropriate object via delegation.

Because the superview will set frame of all subviews with flexible autoresizing mask when autoresizesSubviews is YES, this works, but it involves adding a hidden view inside a view, which is a bit hacky and may create problems in some scenarios (though most are corner cases). I'm still searching for a more suitable/less hacky solution.

Comment: Have you looked at KVO?

Comment: @CrimsonChris according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19701380/811405 it's not a safe approach. it does seem to work according to another answer, but it relies on undocumented behavior which would be subject to change, and I don't want to build a framework/library utilizing undocumented behavior.

Comment: Is subclassing your views an option? You could provide your own way to hook into frame changes that way.

Comment: Swizzling might be another option.

Comment: @CrimsonChris unfortunatelly not. I want my library to be modular and compatible with regular UIViews and be easily integratable. I'm currently working on an "ugly way". See my updated question.

Comment: Both KVO and method swizzling can accomplish what you seek. They both have dangers. Either approach will likely be cleaner than the approach you are taking now.