# How to detect whether the frames of two UIViews are touching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have two `UIView` objects and I want to check whether any portion of their frames are touching each other.

Such as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/use-key-value-observing-to-get-a-kvo-callback-on-a-uiviews-frame

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like you should probably be using UIDynamics (or maybe even SpriteKit). What is it you're actually trying to do once they touch?

Comment: just want to display a msg that they touched...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CGRect` procedures to accomplish what you want. Just check `CGRectIntersectsRect( rect1, rect2)` where `rect1` is the frame of your first view and `rect2` is the frame of the second. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If View 1 goes down vertically then it is easy to tell if they will intersect by checking the .x axis and of course adding the width.

Basically we will check 2 cases, if the *View2.x <= View1.x + View1.width <= View2.x + View2.width*

**Swift example:**

```
let view1TotalWidth = View1.frame.origin.x + View1.frame.size.width
let view2TotalWidth = View2.frame.origin.x + View2.frame.size.width

if View2.frame.origin.x <= view1TotalWidth && view1TotalWidth <= view2TotalWidth {
   print("They will intersect")
}
```

Now we need to check the 2nd case when the right point (which is what we checked above) is now beyond the view2TotalWidth, which is basically almost the same:

*View2.x <= View1.x <= View2.x + View2.width*

Again, the answer is under the assumption that view1 will drop down vertically from his current starting position.