# How to make UIView detect change in parent scale?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

Is there a way to automatically detect when a UIView changes it's apparent scale on the screen, because one of its parents changed scale? Note that I'm not asking how to detect if the UIView's **own** scale property changes, but that of one of its parents?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are several ways to do that (without even searching, I knew we could do that by **KVO, RxSwift, or ReactiveCocoa.**). So, yeah, use KVO if you're not into reactive programming. But I am also thinking you could just use NotificationCenter, sent by your parent view class. I forgot the other way that I was thinking, I was about to type it here but it's gone, sad.

Anyways, example:

```
[self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"transform" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"position" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"zPosition" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"anchorPoint" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"anchorPointZ" options:0 context:NULL];
[self.view.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
```

The code block came from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687115/3231194

I hope this helps!